# Error using dictionary updateValue() with variable but not variable's value

Tags: swift2

I wasn't really sure how to phrase the question, but giving the code seems to be a better way to explain my question:

The following code gives an **error**:

```
var indexDict = [String: [String]]()
var array = ["At", "Ab", "Bs", "BE", "SD"]

for val in self.array { 
     //get the first letter
     let char = val.removeAtIndex(val.startIndex)
     var str = String(char).capitalizedString
     if let _ = Int(str) {
         str = "#"
     }

     //see if it's in the index array, if it isn't add it
     if (indexDict[str] == nil) {
         indexDict.updateValue([val], forKey: str)
     } else {
         indexDict.updateValue(indexDict[str]!.append("\(val)"), forKey: str)
        }
}
```

Error: `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'`

However, this code **doesn't** give an error:

```
var indexDict = [String: [String]]()
var array = ["At", "Ab", "Bs", "BE", "SD"]

for val in self.array { 
     //get the first letter
     let char = val.removeAtIndex(val.startIndex)
     var str = String(char).capitalizedString
     if let _ = Int(str) {
         str = "#"
     }

     //see if it's in the index array, if it isn't add it
     if (indexDict[str] == nil) {
         indexDict.updateValue([val], forKey: str)
     } else {
         var arr = indexDict[str]!
         arr.append("\(val)")
         indexDict.updateValue(arr, forKey: str)
        }
}
```

I don't understand why setting the variable and updating the `Dictionary` with that variable is any different from directly updating the `Dictionary` with the value the variable is assigned to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, it's because in this expression:

```
indexDict[str]!.append
```

...the thing you are trying to `append` to is not a `var` reference. It's just a sort of temporary value floating in mid-expression.

But in this expression:

```
 var arr = indexDict[str]!
 arr.append("\(val)")
```

...you've paused to supply an actual `var` reference for this thing. And that is something you can `append` to.

Comment: The answer is actually much simpler than that: `append` doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that

```
indexDict[str]!.append("\(val)")
```

returns `Void` not an array of strings, which is what is needed in `updateValue()`. This works:

```
indexDict.updateValue(indexDict[str]! + ["\(val)"], forKey: str)
```

Answer (score 0):

resulting type of expression

```
indexDict[str]!.append("\(val)")
```

is Void

You are not able to update your dictionary with Void ...